# Create SQL Server Agent job for stored procedure with input parameter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, jobs

Could you suggest please how to create SQL Server Agent job for a stored procedure that have 1 input parameter?

The procedure is correctly created and i executed it using this code :

```
EXECUTE dbo.MYProcedure N'2016-02-25';
```

Could you suggest please how to create SQL Server Agent job for a stored procedure that have 1 input parameter?

The procedure is correctly created and i executed it using this code :

EXECUTE dbo.MYProcedure N'2016-02-25';
Is there a way to create a SQL Server Agent job for this procedure that have parameter ?

So i'm trying the basic way that is add this ligne in  EXECUTE dbo.MYProcedure N'2016-02-25'; to the window of step in job But the paraméter can change

Comment: How is the parameter decided upon? Is it the current date or does the user need to pass it in? Why can the user not simply use a stored procedure?

Comment: What is the rule that determines the parameter (assuming from your example it is a date)?
Can you calculate this with various date functions at run time and pass it to the procedure as a variable?